# Trying to access only one textbox field inside a repeater template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oledb, repeater

```
  If (dr.Read) Then
            Dim thread As Integer
            thread = Convert.ToInt32(dr(0).ToString())
            For Each rItem As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
                Dim txtBox As HtmlInputText = DirectCast(rItem.FindControl("messtxt"), HtmlInputText)
                If Not IsNothing(txtBox) Then
                    Dim messtxta As String = txtBox.Value
                    cmd2 = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO messages(content) VALUES('" & messtxta.Replace("'", "''") & "')", con)
                    cmd2.Connection = con
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            Next
            Response.Redirect("pals.aspx")
```

The above code works finely for inserting purposes.
Except:
The problem is, if the repeater repeats x number of times, there will be x number of inserts from the textbox, out of which one will be the one I entered.

I only want it to insert one time.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If (dr.Read) Then
        Dim thread As Integer
        Dim txtBox As HtmlInputText
        Dim messtxta As String
        thread = Convert.ToInt32(dr(0).ToString())
        For Each rItem As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
            txtBox = DirectCast(rItem.FindControl("messtxt"), HtmlInputText)
         If Not IsNothing(txtBox) Then 
            IF txtBox.Value.Length > 0 THEN
               messtxta   = txtBox.Value
            END IF
         End If   
        Next

        cmd2 = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO messages(content) VALUES('" & messtxta.Replace("'", "''") & "')", con)
        cmd2.Connection = con
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Response.Redirect("pals.aspx")
```

Comment: Still the same thing happens.

Comment: why ? Insert statement is the out of loop  so only one time insert in db.

Comment: Ok this solves it.
Next problem- content inserted is empty.

Comment: i hope your last row in "messtxt"  value is empty.

Comment: Yep. :P I was just editing that in my code. Thank you so much!